# Value is not an accepted value. Valid values: ["rubocop"] (737, 20)

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, rubocop

I install Ruby and ruby-rubocop extension in my Visual Studio Code, but this warning is showing in my editor:

```
Value is not an accepted value. Valid values: ["rubocop"] (737, 20)
```

When I click in warning redirect to `settings.json (/)`, specifically `"ruby.format": "",`.

```
// ruby language settings

    // Defines where the Ruby extension will look to find Modules, Classes and methods.
    "ruby.locate": {
        "exclude": "{**/@(test|spec|tmp|.*),**/@(test|spec|tmp|.*)/**,**/*_spec.rb}",
        "include": "**/*.rb"
    },

    // Path to the Ruby interpreter.  Set this to an absolute path to select from multiple installed Ruby versions.
    "ruby.interpreter.commandPath": "ruby",

    // Path to the rct-complete command.  Set this to an absolute path to select from multiple installed Ruby versions.
    "ruby.rctComplete.commandPath": "rct-complete",

    // Select the type of formatter to use. If 'rubocop' is selected, the ruby.lint.rubocop options will be passed to the formatter.
    "ruby.format": "",

    // Set individual ruby linters to use
    "ruby.lint": {},
```

In my .vscode/settings.json I try `"ruby.format": "rubocop",` and `"ruby.format": ["rubocop"],` but warning keep showing.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Visual Studio Code solve the problem with `"ruby.format": "rubocop"`, configuration.